# Magicka and co-op

Tags: magicka

What are the differences in terms of story and gameplay between single player and co-op?

A friend and I have just bought Magicka and we are wondering if we should start play in single first or if we can immediatly start play in multiplayer?

Comment: just a (possibly) helpful comment - the new Magicka: Vietnam DLC is out now so you have another reason to play co-op! :)

Comment: @Alex Are there new co-op features in Magicka : Vietnam DLC?

Comment: don't think so...it's already got 4-player co-op, I don't think there are new spells or elements, but I'm not sure so I'd check out some previews if I were you

Comment: A lot of the charm of Magicka, in my experience, is when you and your co-op partner(s) keep accidentally blowing each other up because of your inexpert beam crossing, mine laying, and thunderbolting. Why ruin that by getting good first?

Comment: @Peter Oh yes, we tried yesterday evening. It was hilarious! One of the best hours spent in game, in recent times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The campaign is the same in single player and co-op. There is no reason to play alone first, just start co-op directly.

The game is also better balanced in co-op, IMHO. Single player can get pretty frustrating at times.

Comment: Well, it was worth it given how you dragged me and Tom singlehandedly through the first four chapters!

Comment: @fail It's just far less frustrating if your teammates can just revive you, instead of having to restart from a far away checkpoint every time you die.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I've seen, co-op adventure mode is identical to single player.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as mentioned before.

I wouldn't start in single player, you lack the fun of co-op if you do so... also when playing in co-op, you can do some cool stuff you can't in single player. For example you can cross a water-beam with an electric beam which causes an explosion at the place where the beams cross. Try doing that when you're alone :)